# Стандартный плеер не воспроизводит видео из заданной папки

Tags: java, android

Такая проблема, пытаюсь воспроизвести видео файлы из папки,по нажатию на видео файл  видео плеер запускается,А потом пишется ошибка: **видео не поддерживается.**
Видео корректное и без ошибок,записано с камеры этого же смартфона(файлы воспроизводятся, заходил через total в папку из которой пытаюсь воспроизвести  и видео воспроизводилось стандартным плеером)

метод нахождения файлов с расширением mp4:

```
  public ArrayList<String> getVideoFiles(String directoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    File files[] = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".MP4");
        }
    });

    for (File file : files) {
        result.add(file.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

вызываю метод тут:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoPreviewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mVideoPreviewImageView.setImageBitmap(mItems.get(position).getVideoBitmap());
        holder.mVideoPreviewTextView.setText(mItems.get(position).getVideoName());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PreviewActivity previewActivity = new PreviewActivity();
                ArrayList<String> files = previewActivity
                        .getVideoFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.OtherFile");

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                        String.valueOf(files)));
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.OtherFile")), "video/MP4");
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

Комбинации с :
"video/mp4" /"video/MP4" и return name.endsWith(".MP4");/return name.endsWith(".mp4");
не решают проблемы.

UPDATE:

```
    public class VideoPreviewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoPreviewAdapter.VideoPreviewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<VideoPreview> mItems;
    private List<String> path_vid;

    public VideoPreviewAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addItems(ArrayList<VideoPreview> items) {
        mItems.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearItems() {
        mItems.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public VideoPreviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.video_preview_item, parent, false);
        return new VideoPreviewHolder(view);
    }

   /* public void searchVid(File dir) {
        String pattern = ".MP4";
        //Get the listfile of that flder
        final File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                final int x = i;
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    walkdir(listFile[i]);
                } else {
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pattern)) {
                        // Do what ever u want, add the path of the video to the list
                        path_vid.add(listFile[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoPreviewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mVideoPreviewImageView.setImageBitmap(mItems.get(position).getVideoBitmap());
        holder.mVideoPreviewTextView.setText(mItems.get(position).getVideoName());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               /* PreviewActivity previewActivity = new PreviewActivity();
                ArrayList<String> files = previewActivity
                        .getVideoFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.OtherFile");
                for (String fileArray : files) {

                }*/
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.OtherFile";

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path)));

                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(
                        String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.OtherFile")),
                        "video/MP4");
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public class VideoPreviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mVideoPreviewImageView;
        public TextView mVideoPreviewTextView;

        public VideoPreviewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mVideoPreviewImageView =
                    (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_preview_image_view);
            mVideoPreviewTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_preview_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, Вы нигде не обозначаете **конкретный файл**, который необходимо воспроизвести. Какого результата Вы ждете от кода, который имеет в наличии лишь **путь до папки** или список путей до **нескольких файлов**?

Comment: @ post_zeew
я вас понял, тогда мне нужно получать файл ,А потом передавать в setDataAndType?
а для получения файла я обработчику   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener как должен передать видео файл из папки?

Comment: Ну да, как-то так. У Вас в адаптере есть массив данных, а в методе `onBindViewHolder(...)` у Вас есть `position`. С помощью `position` Вы можете из Вашего массива данных получить конкретный объект и вполне конкретный путь до **выбранного** видео-файла.

Comment: @ post_zeew
`PreviewActivity previewActivity = new PreviewActivity();
                ArrayList<String> files = previewActivity
                        .getVideoFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.OtherFile");

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                        String.valueOf(files)));`
это я оставляю без изменения, циклом прохожу по files а потом получаю элемент + позицию?

Comment: Я точно не знаю, с какими параметрами должен создаваться данный `intent`, но логика подсказывает, что там должно быть не `Uri.parse(String.valueOf(files))`. И это, Вы создаете экземпляр `PreviewActivity` – зачем?

Comment: @post_zeew
то что нужно передавать только путь только до конкретного файла я понял, вопрос тогда в другом ,а получить его как тогда.
У менять есть путь к папке в которой есть файлы, нужно сканировать путь на наличие файлов вот и вызываю PreviewActivity экземпляр  т.к там есть метод получения и добавления файла.

Comment: Покажите код адаптера.

Comment: @post_zeew
нашел такой метод...только не понимаю что подставить в  **walkdir** searchVid

Comment: Ох... Для добавления элементов в список в адаптере используется метод `addItems(...)`, то есть после добавления элементов, эти элементы будут в `mItems`. Каждый элемент содержит, в частности, **путь до конкретного видео-файла**. В методе `onBindViewHolder(...)` можно получить выбранный элемент путем вызова метода `get(position)` объекта `mItems`. А далее из этого элемента можно получить путь до файла с помощью соответствующего геттера.

Comment: Мой Вам совет: оставьте пока Вы это Ваше приложение. Создайте простое приложение, в котором пользователь может добавлять введенные слова в список. После этого, реализуйте вывод уведомления с текстом нажатого элемента списка. Как разберетесь с этим – возвращайтесь к Вашему приложению. Многие моменты станут понятны.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам,может кому нужно будет.

```
String strin = mItems.get(position).getVideoName();
                    File path_file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.OtherFile/" + strin);

                    Intent intent =
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path_file)));

                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path_file)), "video/mp4")
                    ;
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```